# ROS_CANOpen and EPOS4: internal limit active

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, ros-canopen

I’m trying to use ros_canopen to teleoperate a continuum robot working with 11 maxon motors (combination 538252), each controlled by an EPOS4 (24/1.5 can compact) with 24V power, and a PCAN-USB adapter with the latest peak driver connected to my Linux computer. We used to have a minimum functionality library made in-house, which was able to operate the robot, but I wanted to transition to ros_canopen for more functionality but I've been having some trouble.

I want to use CSP mode to control the robot, but when I run it, I will receive an **‘internal limit active’** error on the node, and then my motors will quick-stop. I thought that this was caused by high-current draw but when I monitor the current, it does not exceed even the nominal current of the motors. I can reproduce this error by commanding a speed that is faster then the calculated nominal speed given my supply voltage. However, I have also randomly gotten this error during initialization or regular motion (below max). I have spoken with the maxon help desk, and they were able to help with a lot of other errors, but at this point they believe the problem to be on the ROS side, not with my EPOS config.

If you could help or have any ideas as to the problem, I’d appreciate assistance.  Here is a drive to my node, with all of the config files and everything: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tBFp9VRZpf8uxmKLK2dg7kNKt62DD_Vl?usp=share_link

Thank you!!!